# Is it necessary to install checker framework before I run its eclipse plugin?

Tags: checker-framework

My console print some error when I open its preference dialogue in eclipse.

```
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/NullnessChecker
```

Any advise?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to install the checker framework separately; it comes with the eclipse plugin.

It looks like you are running too old of a JVM. Java 7 or newer is required. You can check what eclipse is using by going to Help->About Eclipse->Installation Details->Configuration and looking for the eclipse.vm= property.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Java 6, but its installation requirements say that "This plugin has been tested on both Eclipse 3.7.2 and 4.2.1 using either Java 6 or 7." See http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/eclipse/

Comment: Ah, it looks like the docs are out of date. A Java 7 vm is required. I've updated the website.